# Need advice on which approach to use for kiosk software development

Tags: architecture, kiosk, kiosk-mode

Recently I've moved projects and even though the new one is a simple one, I've never done something in this field before and I am wondering what would be the best approach when developing always on-screen metro-style kiosk applications for windows. The only mandatory things are OS: Windows 8 and input: barcode scanner, which, as far as I understood, provide the scanned input as standard keyboard input. I know this question is too broad so I've already looked around but I'm having some trouble figuring out the right approach out of inexperience. That aside, any advice for any approach is welcome.

Considering this we are left with a wide variety of technologies that could be used for the actual kiosk software. The software itself won't be complicated either but it needs capabilites to play video, draw and rotate some basic shapes (basically a wheel of fortune) and some basic REST requests. As far as the metro style goes i guess that can be implemented everywhere.

The two options i looked at are .NET or html/css/js.
 For .net i am considering WPF as it can be easily created with the metro style tools and packaged into an .exe that can be auto-started if the system restarts and will be always full-screen on top without a toolbar. What worries me here is the drawing of the wheel as i've browsed around and can see that people are not huge fans of using WPF to draw graphical stuff. The wheel must be dynamic, with a changing number of prices and pictures but other than that nothing special. However, i didn't find any libraries that will do something like that out of the box so there will be some extra effort to implement the entire thing in code.

My other thought was.. since we already have libraries like d3 for js and i've seen that kiosks mostly use browsers, why not implement it as a simple html/js/css webpage with some metro bootstrapping and a drawing library. There will be some browser on the kiosk (Chrome even supports --kiosk mode) that will auto-run fullscreen without a toolbar if the OS restarts and just point to the local html page with parameters.

And the final thing that came to mind: solution 2 + electron on top so it can be packaged as an exe.

I'm looking for general advice on what would be a **good** solution based on performance, ease of development (as far as oh sh*t, this doesn't work, that broke) and security implications. The security implications are mainly concerning in solution 2 & 3 as a pure html page that opens on a full-screen browser doesn't seem that secure. E.g. you manage to somehow right-click on the browser > Save as and suddenly you have access to the underlying file system.

Comment: You may be re-inventing the wheel here. There are quite a few off-the-shelf kiosk solutions (I work at a company that makes one of them) that give you a full screen browser that is already locked down, so that all you need to do is concentrate on developing the html/js/css kiosk content.

Comment: Thanks but this question concerns exactly the html/js/css part of it or rather the use or lack of use of those technologies. Full os lockdown is not what we are looking to do rn and the --kiosk mode of chrome would be sufficient for us :). I just displayed concern about it because i'm not sure how stable it is but i guess that's up to chrome.

Comment: Yeah, there's lots of things that can lead to security breaches. The --kiosk switch doesn't do much to prevent against preventing users from following links to content that you don't want them to be able to access, preventing keystroke combinations that allow the user to disable the kiosk (Windows-L, Alt-ctl-del, etc), or provide some way for the kiosk environment to cleanse itself after a period (clear cookies, reset volume, clear clipboard, etc). As far as stability goes, yes, the version of the browser engine will largely govern that. Good luck with the project!

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications i will keep them in mind :). Just a follow-up on the issues you mentioned that can be useful for other ppl as well - we have no external links nor would the kiosks have keyboards. The only keyboard input that will come in the system is the one from the barcode scanner. Cookie clearing we can handle with plain js on some timeout interval.